# How do I GROUP BY a datetime with an offset?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has two columns. `day`, a `datetime` column, and `overall`, an `int`. Users are asked to record data once per hour. However, if the user is asleep there will be no new data.

I'm trying to get the daily average. I currently have this query:

```
SELECT day, AVG(overall) AS overall FROM log GROUP BY DATE(day)
```

However, if there is an entry for the early morning (1-4am), it will be grouped with the *previous* day's average.  For example, February 2nd at 1AM should be averaged with the data for February 1st.

How do I `GROUP BY` with an offset so that the early morning will be included in the previous day's average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping by the `day`, you can `GROUP BY` the `day` offset by subtracting 4 hours:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(t.theDate, INTERVAL 4 HOUR), t.overall
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_SUB(day, INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AS theDate, AVG(overall) AS overall
    FROM log
    GROUP BY DATE_SUB(day, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
) t
```

This will have the effect of forcing the first 4 hours of each day back into the previous day.

I wrapped the query because you probably want to still report for each actual 24 hour day, but using the results from aggregating over the shifted schedule.